# How to calculate CRC32-C checksum with zlib

Tags: zlib, crc

I am using the C zlib API because it has the `crc32_combine` function to concatenate checksums together, whereas the Boost one does not.

However, I need to implement the CRC32-C (Castagnoli) checksum, with polynomial `0x1EDC6F41`, instead of the standard CRC32 checksum.

With Boost I can apparently use:

```
#include <boost/crc.hpp>

using crc_32c_type = boost::crc_optimal<32, 0x1EDC6F41, 0xFFFFFFFF, 0xFFFFFFFF, true, true>;
crc_32c_type result;
result.process_bytes(reinterpret_cast<const char*>(&buffer), len);
return result.checksum();
```

Which can use the `0x1EDC6F41` polynomial.

Is there a similar way for me to do this with zlib?

Comment: You could adapt this for your needs https://github.com/torvalds/linux/blob/master/include/linux/crc32.h#L41

Comment: Thank you for the suggestion. Actually, just to get things working I could also just stick to boost and just use process_bytes on chunks of my buffer to achieve the same "combining" effect.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

zlib is open source. You can simply take the source and modify for your own needs. You can change the line: `odd[0] = 0xedb88320UL;` to the reflection of the Castagnoli polynomial.

Answer (score 0):

**For Objective C**

Took me a while to find one that worked.

```
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
//                    crc32c
//           Calculate crc32c (Castagnoli) Checksum
//------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
+ (uint32_t) crc32c:(NSData *)data {
    /* CRC-32C (iSCSI) polynomial in reversed bit order. */


    int k;
    const unsigned char *buf = [data bytes];
    unsigned long len = [data length];
    uint32_t crc = 0xFFFFFFFF;
    while (len--) {
        crc ^= *buf++;
        for (k = 0; k < 8; k++)
            //CRC-32C polynomial 0x1EDC6F41 in reversed bit order.
            crc = crc & 1 ? (crc >> 1) ^ 0x82f63b78 : crc >> 1;
    }
    return ~crc;
}
```